# Hold the data with in the form when page refresh or back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, autosave

I have a jsp form, which has textboxes,radio buttons,select and text areas. How can I persist/hold the data within the form even when I refresh the page or coming back to this page from the the next. I need an auto save functionality(don't need to save in to the database just holds the data). Can anybody suggest some information/links? Can I do it with jQuery or javascript?I don't have an idea to implement this.

Comment: use session to save use ajax to pass form data before page refresh.

Answer (score 3):

`Can I do it with jQuery or javascript?`

Absolutely. You can use cookies to store the data and the same can be used to fill in the details when the page is refreshed. But I recommend using a plugin, just to make life easier.

Some of the jquery plugins that do this - [jQuery Save As You Type](https://github.com/BenGriffiths/jquery-save-as-you-type), [jQuery dumbFormState](https://github.com/sebringj/jquery.dumbformstate)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Html5 local storage: 
    http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/
    http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp